# Relative positioned element disappears when it inline displayed?

Tags: html, css, css-position, display

i try toput diplay inline in relative positioned  element heres  the code

```
.parent{
height: 50px;
width: 130px;
background-color: red;
top: 100px;
position: relative;
display: inline;
}
```

but it just disappear 
my question is why it do and what the relation between position and display

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection between position and display. But, in your case. Change `display: inline;` to `display: inline-block;`, and the element will appear. Displayd `inline` element can ignore `width` and `height` and will be invisible without content.

Comment: *There is no connection between position and display.* --> it depends on the position. If it was absolute of fixed then the display will get affected

Comment: I see. I mean, in these case. The main issue here is `display: inline;`